# photo gallery jqm plugin

Tags: jquery, image-gallery, jquery-mobile

i am developing an application for 4 different mobile platforms, iOS , Android , WP7 , BB.

I am trying to implement a plugin in my jquery mobile page that will run in all of these platforms.  I have the links of some photos and i need to be able to show the photos to the user like a gallery , create albums of photos etc. I have found [this](https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe) plugin called PhotoSwipe which seems exactly what i need but unfortunately i think it wont work with WP7.

Do you have in mind a plugin that you have used and worked with these platforms? Or at least point me to the right direction of some plugins that could work here.

Thank you very much for reading my post.

Comment: You should show your work effort whatever you have done so far. So that others can help you to identify cause of error.

Comment: I am actually looking for a plugin that does what i described. However every one of them is missing smth (eg support one of the platforms). Thats why i am asking here for someone that has done this before , to recommend a plugin that has been tested and is stable upon release. I havent started coding yet as i need to make this decision first.